# How can I create a parallel stream from an array?

Tags: java, arrays, parallel-processing, java-8, java-stream

I can create a Stream from an array using `Arrays.stream(array)` or `Stream.of(values)`. Similarly, is it possible to create a ParallelStream directly from an array, *without creating an intermediate collection* as in `Arrays.asList(array).parallelStream()`?

Comment: `Arrays.stream(array).parallel()`? I suppose you could have `StreamSupport.stream(Arrays.spliterator(array), true)` as well, but why make it complicated?

Comment: Each stream can be converted to parallel via `parallel()` method. So you could simply use `Stream.of(elements).parallel()`.

Answer (score 56):

```java
Stream.of(array).parallel()
```

or

```java
Arrays.stream(array).parallel()
```

Comment: Interestingly, I added this to one of my programs and it brought the runtime from 13ms to 90ms. This was on leetcode, I'm guessing a lot of their test cases are of a smaller size where parallelization brings in more overhead than actually speeding anything up - https://i.imgur.com/sHc8lLG.png

Comment: @Siddhartha parallel does not imply faster, yes.

Comment: leetcode adds runtime for every concurrent thread so it will always be slower even if the program finished faster than single thread.

Answer (score 9):

**TLDR;**

Any sequential `Stream` can be converted into a parallel one by calling `.parallel()` on it. So all you need is:

1. Create a stream
2. Invoke method `parallel()` on it.

**Long answer**

The question is pretty old, but I believe some additional explanation will make the things much clearer.

All implementations of Java streams implement interface `BaseStream`. Which as per JavaDoc is:

> Base interface for streams, which are sequences of elements supporting sequential and parallel aggregate operations.

From API's point of view there is no difference between sequential and parallel streams. They share the same aggregate operations.

In order do distinguish between sequential and parallel streams the aggregate methods call `BaseStream::isParallel` method.

Let's explore the implementation of `isParallel` method in `AbstractPipeline`:

```
@Override
public final boolean isParallel() {
    return sourceStage.parallel;
}
```

As you see, the only thing `isParallel` does is checking the boolean flag in source stage:

```
/**
 * True if pipeline is parallel, otherwise the pipeline is sequential; only
 * valid for the source stage.
 */
private boolean parallel;
```

So what does the `parallel()` method do then? How does it turn a *sequential* stream into a *parallel* one?

```
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public final S parallel() {
    sourceStage.parallel = true;
    return (S) this;
}
```

Well it only sets the `parallel` flag to `true`. That's all it does.

As you can see, in current implementation of Java Stream API it doesn't matter how you create a stream (or receive it as a method parameter). You can always turn a stream into a parallel one with zero cost.